# How to get value from parent component?

Tags: angular

I have wrapper component `app-content-show` that shows/hides content (others components):

```
<app-content-show>
    <div header_p>Block 1<div>
    <div content_p>
       <app-list-users></app-list-users>
       <!-- Another component -->
       <!-- Another component 2-->
       <!-- Another component 3 -->
    </div>
</app-content-show>
```

This component contains local varaible `public show = false;` that controls when to show content projection `content_p`.

How to get this variable in children component `<app-list-users></app-list-users>`? How to listen this each time when it is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a `*ngIf`, so something like this

```
<app-content-show>
    <div header_p>Block 1<div>
    <div content_p>
       <app-list-users *ngIf="show"></app-list-users>
       <!-- Another component *ngIf="show" -->
       <!-- Another component2 *ngIf="show" -->
       <!-- Another component3 *ngIf="show" -->
    </div>
</app-content-show>
```

I did a quick try in an existing Stackblitz and it seems to be working. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-content-projection-example-8f9nmy?file=src/app/content-proj/main-comp/main-comp.component.ts) (I added it to `main-comp.component.ts`). Like this you don't need to change your children. You need to add `*ngIf` everywhere but I don't think that's too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide variable as parameter:

```
  <app-content-show>
    <div header_p>Block 1<div>
        <div content_p>
           <app-list-users [show]="show" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </app-content-show>
```

Comment: I dont want to pollute children components by this variable. Is there any solutions, because there a lot of child components

Comment: Yes, you can use https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Also, you can use external libs like rxjs or redux for state management.